# apostrophe is not stored in Mysql database while scraping data from website

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to store a string in Mysql database. That string was extracted from the HTML page.

i have used `mysqli_real_escape_string()` PHP function but still it is not storing apostrophe.

It is showing `ÃƒÂ¢Ã‚Â€Ã‚Â™` instead of apostrophe.

```
database collation: latin1_swedish_ci
```

Comment: Can you post your insert query?

Comment: @Sadikhasan insert into app_db (app_desc) values ($app_desc) , $app_desc is the variable containing the text...

Comment: $app_desc contains which type of text?

Comment: @Sadikhasan insert into db (app_description) values ($app_description) ;

Comment: thats the matter app_desc doesn't contain an apostrophe . wow !!

Comment: I mean  i want text that you want to insert in database

Comment: The text: "One of India’s most respected newspapers, The Hindu is known for its classic yet contemporary design and its authentic and credible journalism. The Hindu Android app lives up to that reputation and offers a rich experience and depth of coverage that few media brands can match."

Comment: what is your data type in database for this field?

Comment: i have used text datatype

Comment: why would you use latin1_swedish_ci for this?

Comment: @ben it is by default

Comment: @stacky change it... to something usable like utf8_general_ci

Comment: Use `$variable = addslashes(mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['variable']));` to store apostrophes correctly. @stacky

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your database collation  to `utf8_general_ci`

OR change the column type to `BLOB`. so your collation will be empty.

I think that will work.

Comment: i have used few functions now it is storing the special characters in raw format like apostrophe in &#8217; how can i store apostrophe as it is.??